# How to test mobile chrome's "save to homescreen" prompt

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-applications, service-worker

I'm resurrecting [an old project](https://postednot.es/) of mine as a way to learn some new stuff.

I'm doing [this code lab from IO](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2016#0) *Add Your Web App to a User's Home Screen*.

Is there any way, other than connecting a phone and waiting a lot, to test if users will be shown the prompt below?

[image: Add to home screen prompt]

I've tested it with [Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) and all tests come back green, but I've never seen the prompt. It feels very random at the moment.

The answer to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199615/how-to-add-to-add-to-homescreen-popup-for-android-mobile) puts the stuggle into perspective:

> The user has visited your site twice over two separate days during the course of two weeks

Does that mean I need to wait 2 days between changes to see if it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Enable chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks and you will see the banner as long as you have a manifest (configured correctly) and are on HTTPS and have a service worker.

[Increasing Engagement with Web App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

[anshulix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2940289/anshulix) has correctly answered the question, but I thought I'd put in a more verbose answer.

---

To remove the waiting and other requirements for the *save to homescreen* prompt, then you need to enable a flag.

> Enable chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks and you will see the banner as long as you have a manifest (configured correctly) and are on HTTPS and have a service worker.

Which comes from [Increasing Engagement with Web App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android?hl=en)

It's important to remember that you are setting this flag on the *mobile browser*, not on your desktop browser. For some reason this didn't occur to be for a while!

You also need to restart mobile Chrome for the flag to take effect. If you've got your tabs mixed in with your other apps, this can be tricky because you need to hunt down all the tabs and close them. (Or find a better way to close Chrome.)

I found it much easier to do this debugging in [Chrome Dev](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.dev), rather than regular chrome because a) I know it's got the latest fixes in it, and b) because I only have 1 tab open, so it's easy to restart the browser.

---

If you are doing remote inspection, there is [an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595517) about the messages that come up in the console. In Chrome 50 you get:

> App banner not shown: could not determine the best icon to use

This doesn't seem to be true; in more recent builds—e.g. mobile Chrome 52—*save to desktop* works just fine. It's a disconcerting but useless error.

---

As a bonus helpful thing, [realfavicongenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) does an excellent job of generating all the icons and the manifest file that you need.

Comment: Nicely explained :)